# Missing titles in palettes with Win 8

Tags: windows, palettes

I just noticed that MMA (8 and 10) in Windows 8 on my machine does not display the title of any palette. For ex. Basic Math Assistant palette appears without title. Same with user-defined palettes
Can you confirm this or it is just my Win 8?
If it is just me, as I suspect, can anybody suggest any setting change to Win 8 that I may perform in order to show titles in palettes?
Titles in notebooks are ok.

Comment: The title appears on mine. **Windows 8.1**

Comment: Thanks @RunnyKine . The problem likely depends on my machine. I updated the question. Any suggestion is welcomed